# stackdriver: how to share a particular dashboard ONLY

Tags: stackdriver

newbie here, created a dashboard with a few charts, intended to share with another team of users, however, have other dashboard within the same workspace, the intention is to only share a particular dashboard not the others. Scanning through the documentation only says an IAM controls the monitoring viewer, but how to further constraint to a specific dashboard?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Stackdriver there is currently no way to share a single dashboard in a project that has multiple dashboards.

You could [publicly share](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/sharing-charts) individual charts from a dashboard. Note that anyone who knows the URL of the chart would be able to view it.

A project can only be associated to one workspace.  You can have multiple projects in one workspace.  So you would have to create a new project and stream metric/log data to that project and create a new workspace associated to that project.  That workspace would have only the dashboard you wanted to share.

Comment: looks like cannot create another workspace for the same project. a public chart is not an option, running into a wall here

Comment: Do you not have permissions to create a new workspace?  what is the specific issue you are running into?

Comment: follow the recommendation, my intention is to create another workspace in the same project, then create dashboard then share from there. however in the new workspace, I did not see the project in the dropdown list, so the question, can you create multiple workspaces targeting same project?

Comment: A project can only be associated to one workspace.  You can have multiple projects in one workspace.  So you would have to create a new project and stream metric/log data to that project and create a new workspace associated to that project.  That workspace would have only the dashboard you wanted to share.